# Alternatives to XTEA as encryption algorithms for stenography

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

I recently implemented an algorithm written in Python that was using the XTEA encryption method.

Are there any more reliable algorithms than the XTEA , regarding to memory usage and PSNR ratio ,other than integrity,  which do not encounter drastic degradation of image and fulfill the requirements of a imperceptibility steganography benchmark?

Comment: The reason of choosing XTEA over other encryption algorithm is because it is a lightweight block cipher that generally extremely simplify the key schedule due to memory requirements.... On the contrary, the need of read-only memory is very diﬀerent from one algorithm to an other. Whereas TEA and XTEA requires only 1354 and 1394 bytes of ROM to execute, KTANTAN requires 16252 bytes in its 64-bits version. Indeed AES ,  TEA and XTEA are the only ones that require less than 2000 cycles/byte.

Comment: I used XTEA  also  because PNSR values above 40dB. Hence, it  can greatly reduce the possibility of the message being read, modified, tempered etc . At least using LSB method. the encrypted message will be embedded in a cover object by using least significant bit substitution at each pixel of the cover image. I reformulate the question, probably was not clear.

Comment: Peak Signal to Noise Ratio does not depend on the (secure) encryption algorithm used. It depends on the stenography method used, and XTEA is not one. Again, why would AES not be suitable? Are you coding for a very space-constrained device, or one where there is no ready-made native AES encryption usable from python, or prevented from doing this by the problem statement?

Comment: yes inded i need to deal with ROM limited usage. Also the XTEA was supposed to be embedded with a session key generati

Comment: Also the XTEA was  to be embedded with a time session key generator. Probably AES would be better than XTEA , but slower. Thank You btw!

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer , attached the memory usage and SW performance tables :

[image]
[image]